# One small patch on wall (white before) not covered by primer or 3 coats of paint

Tags: plumbing, painting, repainting

Hoping someone can help- moved in to a new house and decided to paint the living room today (Warm Pewter by Dulux) after testing a few colours. There was one tiny spot before which was light grey on pebble paint (noticed yesterday) so after making the walls good with filler and sanding then priming it was ok- now i have painted it seems to be coming through again like some sort of stain, and unsure what it could be- everywhere else is fine. When touched after 1st and second coat this did not seem wet , but then i scratcher at it and paint came off! (not sure if worth a mention but this is near my kitchen ) wall - could it be some sort of weird leak, has anyone seen this issue before? (Looked briefly behind the washing machine and was all dry)

Comment: I would venture to guess that had you scratched at the paint anywhere, it would have come up. it takes awhile for some paint to *cure*, even though it feels dry.